# Organic group module- teacher student layout dashbord

Tags: 7

drupal7- Organic group. Each teacher manages a class composed of several groups. Teachers only have access to their own groups. By connecting each teacher is directed to a page (or dashboard homebox) containing: its student groups with each group their latest posts, a link to their blogs , a place to send (create) a post to all groups or a specific group. Each group of students connect with the user name and password of the administrator of the group (one group member has the right to connect) and are directed to a page that contains: All posts sent by the group, members of the group, a place to send (create) a post (blog entry) only to the teacher, and a page explaining the course. How much do I create roles (teachers and students only?) which modules should I use? og, og_menu, og-audience ...

Answer (score 0):

Thats possible out of the box.. see http://nodeone.se/en/permissions-and-roles-for-groups